# if statement based on form select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic form:

```
<%=form_for @person do |f| %>
<%= f.label :ThingsWanted, "Stuff I need" %>
<%= f.select :ThingsWanted, ['cat', 'dog', 'purse', 'lipstick', 'fish'], { :include_blank => 'Selector' }, :required => true %>
<%= f.submit 'Done'%>
<%end%>
```

What I want to do is created an if statement based on what is selected before the form is submitted. Say lipstick is selected

Then I want to create a new form value called explain_yourself

```
<%if lipstick is selected%>
 explain_yourself goes here
<%end%>
```

I don't know how to create the if-statement or rather access the select value before the form is submitted...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.
Add a class to the form and also to the input tag in question in the HTML

```
<%=form_for @person do |f|  :class => "the_form_class" %>

<%= f.select :ThingsWanted, ['cat', 'dog', 'purse', 'lipstick', 'fish'], { :include_blank => 'Selector' }, :class => "the_input_class" :required => true %>
```

then in jquery, add an on-submit function to the form

```
$(".the_form_class").on("submit", some_function)
```

note: make sure you wrap this on-submit event handler in a document.ready

then define that function (the definition does not need to be wrapped in a document.ready)

```
function some_function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  if( $(".the_input_class").val() == "lipstick"){
    do_some_stuff

  }
 $(".the_form_class").submit();
}
```

Comment: the e.preventDefault stops the form from actually being submitted.  Then it runs the code. Then the .submit() actually submits the form after the if statement has been evaluated

Comment: I am sorry, I am looking for a ruby-based solution if one exists. This doesn't really work for me. My actual form is much larger and complex. I was hoping there was a simple way to access the select value and use some embedded ruby to keep it clean.

Answer (score 0):

This best workaround I found for this was using parameters and instance variables. Sorry the example is not great, but it works.

```
Do you have lipstick?
<%= link_to "Yes", onclick: @a=0%></td>
<%= link_to "No", onclick: @a=1%>
<% if params[:onclick].to_i == 1%>
    <%= f.label :ThingsWanted, "Stuff I need" %>
    <%= f.select :ThingsWanted, ['lipstick'], { :include_blank => 'Selector' }, :class => "the_input_class" :required => true %>
<%else%>
<br/>
    <%= f.label :explain_yoself, "Select what you need" %>
    <%= f.select :ThingsWanted, ['cat', 'dog', 'purse', 'fish'], { :include_blank => 'Selector' }, :required => true %>
    <%= f.text_area :explain_yourself %>
<%end%>
```